# Call python script with angular 2 application

Tags: python, angular, typescript, browser

Is there any way to call a python script inside browser from my typescript file in angular 2 or later version of the same?

Comment: python does not run in the browser ... the browser only understands javascript html and css (for the most part)

Comment: @JoranBeasley please check this out [brython](https://brython.info/)

Comment: that just converts python to js ... you probably get most of the builtin features of python3 ... but not much for libraries ... im sure there is some webpack-loader to be able to write .bry files or something ...  (or maybe even .py?) but its really not python(although im sure they implemented the whole interpreter(ie language rules)) there are many "solutions" like this ... (Im also sure there is a `brython.compile(raw_python)` type of directive)

Comment: thanks for the information @JoranBeasley